# sshfs mounted directory - Operation not permitted

Tags: filesystem, vpn, mount

I have been facing this 'Operation not permitted' problem and tried to solve it with different solutions found on the internet but none of them helped. Hoping to get some insights here.

I usually mount directory after connecting to VPN with `sshfs`. Everything was working fine till this morning and all of a sudden I'm getting 'Operation not permitted' error when I `mv` or create new files within mounted directories. I didn't change anything that caused this.

I use following version

```
macOS High Sierra, 10.13.6

sshfs --version
SSHFS version 2.5 (OSXFUSE SSHFS 2.5.0)
OSXFUSE 3.8.2
FUSE library version: 2.9.7
fuse: no mount point
```

Any leads how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much & stay safe!